# Why does the PHP operator not work as intended?

Tags: php

So, the operator I'm using isn't working, and I'm probably just being really dumb.

Here is the context. This is in PHP.

You can "breed" as long as `>= 3`. However, this must exclude the type of "sterile", "impotent" and "infertile".

It would appear that using `>=3` with `AND !=` or using `||` to include all 3 won't work.

For a singular type, it'll work with `AND`/`&& >=3 && $stuff['type'] != "sterile") {`. But, when using more than one type, it goes crazy and won't exclude them.

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: sorry, I didn't give enough information the first time.

The first attempt was:

```
if ($pet['id'] != $selected['id'] && $pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] =! "impotent" || $pet['type'] =! "sterile" || $pet['type'] =! "infertile")  {
```

Second was (this code exists further up within my script)

```
if ($pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] =! "impotent" || $pet['type'] =! "sterile" || $pet['type'] =! "infertile") {
```

Third was

```
if ($pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] =! "impotent" OR $pet['type'] =! "sterile" OR $pet['type'] =! "infertile") {
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code that is causing the problem (although sounds like you just need to use brackets to group your conditions)

Comment: I don't know what project you're working on, but I'm intrigued.

Comment: Without seeing what you're trying to do, I'm taking a wild guess and saying that it should probably be something like `if ($var >= 3 && !in_array($type, ['sterile', 'impotent', 'infertile']) {`

Answer (score 0):

Qirel suggestion is the correct answer.
Just wanted to explain what is wrong with your code. So bear with me and my long answer.

First attempt

`if ($pet['id'] != $selected['id'] && $pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] =! "impotent" || $pet['type'] =! "sterile" || $pet['type'] =! "infertile")  {`

1. `=!` is wrong, it should be `!=`
2. Need to do an && (AND), all conditions must be met.

`if ($pet['id'] != $selected['id'] && $pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] != "impotent" && $pet['type'] != "sterile" && $pet['type'] != "infertile")  {`

Second attempt

`if ($pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] =! "impotent" || $pet['type'] =! "sterile" || $pet['type'] =! "infertile") {`

Same as first:

`if ($pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] != "impotent" && $pet['type'] != "sterile" && $pet['type'] =! "infertile") {`

Third attempt

`if ($pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] =! "impotent" OR $pet['type'] =! "sterile" OR $pet['type'] =! "infertile") {`

Same as second (OR is equal to ||)

`if ($pet['tier'] >= 3 && $pet['type'] != "impotent" && $pet['type'] != "sterile" && $pet['type'] =! "infertile") {`

You have to 'run' the logic step by step. Let's use Qirel's solution:

`if ($pet['tier'] >= 3 && !in_array($pet['type'], ['sterile', 'impotent', 'infertile'])`

ie 1:

```
  $pet['tier'] = 4
  $pet['type'] = 'awesome'
```

`4 >= 3 && !in_array('awesome', ['sterile', 'impotent', 'infertile'])  === True && !False === True && True === True`      <=== Answer

ie 2:

```
  $pet['tier'] = 4
  $pet['type'] = 'sterile'
```

`4 >= 3 && !in_array('sterile', ['sterile', 'impotent', 'infertile'])  === True && !True === True && False === False`      <=== Answer

ie 3:

```
  $pet['tier'] = 2
  $pet['type'] = 'Sporty'
```

`2 >= 3 && !in_array('Sporty', ['sterile', 'impotent', 'infertile'])  === False && !False === False && True === False`      <=== Answer

ie 4:

```
  $pet['tier'] = 1
  $pet['type'] = 'sterile'
```

`1 >= 3 && !in_array('sterile', ['sterile', 'impotent', 'infertile'])  === False && !True === False && False === False`      <=== Answer